# How does outlook encrypt the password for windows credentials

Tags: security, outlook, exchange-server, credentials, password-encryption

I using IMsgServiceAdmin::ConfigureMsgService to configure a outlook profile for my exchange server.

When calling this function, windows will popup a dialog to enter the credentials. After I enter the credentials and save, I found it will create a Generic Credentials : MS.Outlook:@.:PUT and the password is encrypted. Such as "@@...yBA"

I would like to how does outlook encrypt my password as I want to manually create the credentials before I call ConfigureMsgService so that the credentials windows won't show.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using SspiEncodeStringsAsAuthIdentity and SspiEncodeStringsAsAuthIdentity, the problem solved

Comment: can you share how you did it with the `SspiEncodeStringsAsAuthIdentity` ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Senior Escalation Engineer for Outlook here at Microsoft and received this exact question from a customer in the past. We asked the product team if they would be able to document the format used to publish credentials in credential manager. The answer is, no, we can't, because we routinely change the format as new scenarios crop up. It may not be obvious, but the target name of the credential will be different for different scenarios. That's the critical part. Without knowing all of the details for constructing that target name, knowing how to protect the password won't help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I already know the target name and know how to contruct the target name for MS.Outlook:<name>@<server>.<domain>:PUT. I would like to know how to create this encrypted password from my password so that outlook can use that

Comment: That target name format has changed in the (recent) past and will likely change again.

Answer (score 3):

For Outlook 2010 and below, use CryptProtectData(). The data to protect is a Unicode string containing the password. The length of the data (in bytes) is 2*length of the password in chars excluding terminating 0x0.

For Outlook 2013 and up, CryptProtectData is not used - CredWrite takes the password.